# How do I change the format of a cell in excel 2013 based on multiple cells within the same row

Tags: excel

I am trying to change the color of one cell in a row if any other cell in that row equals a text value. I have been able to do this with the value of just one cell in the row, but I cannot get it to work within set range of cells.The formula for one cell I have used is : =$E$3="SELECTED" applies to =$C$3 and the format I want is a green fill. If I try to change to =$E$3:$M$3="SELECTED" applies to =$C$3, it won't work for that cell range in the row. I'm at a loss to come up with the correct formula and can't seem to find the right way to ask google the question !!!! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you're acessing Excel through a programming language, this is not the right SE section to ask this question. Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: @MeanGreen, not quite. Formula logic is covered here, too. That's what the tags are for. There are plenty of formula logic questions on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to conditionally format a cell in column C if any of the cells in columns E to M in the same row equals "Selected".

You can use Countif in a conditional formatting formula to achieve this

The formula applied to the range C3 to C6 in the following screenshot is

=COUNTIF($E3:$M3,"selected")

If the count is 0, no formatting will be applied.

[image]

Comment: Teylyn, thank you so much. That is exactly the formula I was after. I wish I hadn't wasted 4 hours buggering around with modifying the single cell rule. Now......you rule !!!!!!.